# Removing items from a structure array in matlab

Tags: matlab, structure, removeall

I have a very large structure array in matlab. Suppose, for argument's sake, to simplify the situation, I have something like:

```
structure(1).name = 'a';
structure(2).name = 'b';
structure(3).name = 'c';
structure(1).returns = 1;
structure(2).returns = 2;
structure(3).returns = 3;
```

Now suppose I have some condition that comes along and makes me want to delete everything from `structure(2)` (any and all entries in my structure array).  What is a good way to do that?

My solution has been to just set the corresponding fields to `[]` (e.g. `structure(1).name = [];`), but that doesn't remove them, that only makes them empty. How do I actually remove them completely from the structure array? Is there a way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

simple if you want to delete element at index `i` do the following:

```
i = 3
structure(i) = [];
```

And that will remove element at index `3`.

Example:

```
st.name = 'text';
st.id = 1524;
arrayOfSt = [st st st st st];
```

Now:

```
arrayOfSt = 

    1x5 struct array with fields:
        name
        id
```

If we execute:

```
arrayOfSt(2) = [];
```

then the new value of the array of structers will be:

```
arrayOfSt = 

    1x4 struct array with fields:
        name
        id
```

Try it !